# Real versus complex Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, complex-numbers

While a Hamiltonian must be a Hermitian matrix, it can either be real or complex. Is there a  significance for having a real Hamiltonian? Does it have any additional physical symmetries?

For example, a two-band tight-binding model has Hamiltonian of the form

$$\sum_k \left( \epsilon_1 c_{k1}^\dagger c_{k1}+\epsilon_2 c_{k2}^\dagger c_{k2}+t c_{k1}^\dagger c_{k2} + t^* c_{k2}^\dagger c_{k1}\right).$$

Does a real $t$ tell us anything physical about the system?

Comment: Note that any self-adjoint operator has a diagonalization as a diagonal real matrix. Not sure what it means for a self-adjoint operator to be "real" or "complex" in light of that, what do you mean?

Comment: @ACuriousMind In some cases it is possible to find a real matrix representation without diagonalization, i.e. if the Hamiltonian possesses spinless time-reversal symmetry. This is what OP means I guess.

Comment: Everyone is making a big deal that you can find a basis in which the Hamtilonian has the noted properties, but the interesting question is what it means *in one particular basis* to have those properties or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The realness of the interorbital coupling $t$ can indeed tell us something about the symmetries of the system. Here, it entails at least one symmetry: *spinless time-reversal symmetry*.

Consider the Hamiltonian of non-interacting spinless particles that live on a periodic chain with two orbitals in each unit cell as in OP's example. In this case, the Hamiltonian can be block-diagonalized by using the periodicity of our system:
\begin{equation}
H = \sum_k \begin{pmatrix} c^\dagger_{k1} & c^\dagger_{k2} \end{pmatrix} H(k) \begin{pmatrix} c_{k1} \\ c_{k2} \end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}
where $H(k)$ is a $2\times 2$ block, labelled by the momentum $k$, called the Bloch Hamiltonian. Now assume that the system has time-reversal symmetry. This means that $[H,T]=0$ with $T$ the time-reversal operator. For spinless particles it is given by $T=K$ with $K$ complex conjugation with respect to the position representation (see e.g. Sakurai). Since $T c_{k,i} = c_{-k,i}$, we find
\begin{equation}
H = THT^{-1} \Rightarrow H(-k) = TH(k)T^{-1} = H(k)^*.
\end{equation}
In OP's example, a periodic chain of cells with no tunnelling between them is considered. Essentially an infinite amount of isolated atoms. The Bloch Hamiltonian is
\begin{equation}
H(k) = \begin{pmatrix} \epsilon_1 & t \\ t^* & \epsilon_2 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
so that the total Hamiltonian $H$ is not time-reversal symmetric if $t$ is not real.

Another example which illustrates the effect of spinless time-reversal symmetry in a periodic system is given by graphene. Here, spinless $T$ and inversion protect the nodes in the band spectrum (Dirac points) locally since combined they forbid any $\sigma_z$ term which would open the energy gap. The two Dirac points can only be destroyed if they merge in a time-reversal-invariant point of the Brillouin zone.

Generally, if time-reversal symmetry is present, the energy spectrum plotted as a function of $k$ (the so-called energy bands) is symmetric with respect to $k$: $E_i(-k) = E_j(k)$. However, the converse is not true since spatial symmetries such as inversion can also enforce a symmetric spectrum.

**Spinful time reversal**

In the case of a half-integer spin system, it can be shown that the time-reversed state $T\left| \psi \right>$ is orthogonal to $\left| \psi \right>$ as a result of $T^2 = -1$ (Kramers' theorem). This means that the energy bands have to become degenerate in time-reversal-invariant points $k = -k + G$ where $G$ is a reciprocal lattice vector. A system with two bands is therefore always a metal. The simplest model for an insulator requires four bands.

Comment: "if there exists a real symmetric matrix representation without diagonalizing $H$" is a weird ask. All hermitian hamiltonians have real, symmetric (diagonal) representations. Are you explicitly asking for a real symmetric representation that's explicitly *not* diagonal? That's also always a thing unless $H$ is completely degenerate. (Find an eigenbasis and rotate two states from different eigenspaces into even + odd real combinations.) Your construction is nice but it's not clear what sets $T$-commuting hamiltonians apart from regular hermitian ones.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thanks for your comment. What sets it apart is exactly this "weird ask". Note that the construction did not require to first diagonalize the Hamiltonian, while yours does.

Comment: The construction is nice but the result - unless you clarify - is the same. All hermitian hamiltonians have real matrix elements in some representation. What does $[H,T]=0$ have to do with it?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I have updated my answer. The discussion on the "real" Hamiltonians was superfluous. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to revive this, but shouldn't it be $H(k) = TH(k)T^{-1} = H(k)^*$?

Comment: @Bcpicao Time reversal commutes with the full Hamiltonian $H = \sum_k c_k^\dagger H(k) c_k$ where $H(k)$ is the Bloch Hamiltonian. Because $Tc_kT^{-1} = c_{-k}$ (write $c_k$ in real space to see this), there is a sign change of the momentum. This also makes sense physically, since time reversal flips the direction of motion.